# Where's my android plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was updating the android plugin for the API 17 (Android 4.2) in my Eclipse Indigo (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), so when i rebooted the Eclipse the plugin has gone and i couldnt open my last project! i tried install the plugin again but it said i've already installed. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue only once.  I couldn't find any way to repair it and chose the path of uninstalling and reinstalling.

**To uninstall:**
About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Select all that start with Android -> Uninstall ...

It is a pain, but at least it will allow you to re-install the plugin.

Comment: it is a real pain, because i have to wait all that time again '--

Comment: I agree, I wasn't pleased with the solution either.  But, for many it isn't obvious how to uninstall the plugin, so at least this gives a clear workaround.

Comment: dude, i'm having troubles trying to "reinstall" the plugin, i've unistall Eclipse, but it does not work, the problem is: "Duplicate Location" so i cant install the plugin. Please, help me.